# Differences between Android NetBEANS plugin and Eclipse plugin?

Tags: android, eclipse, netbeans

Would like to know the main differences between the Android NetBEANS plugin and Eclipse plugin ? Do you have a visual editor in both or one of both ? Do you have more support on Eclipse ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think its a matter of personal preference, but I think Eclipse with ADT plugin is recommended by Google for good reasons.

ADT simplifies things by generating build scripts for you and allows you to drag and drop files into your project and auto generates references in R.Java file.

It sounds to me  that you might be new to Android/Java development? If that's the case then my personal opinion is stick with the Google recommendations. It saves you a lot of time getting your first android application up and running and I think that's the goal for most people starting a new development language.

Comment: Even if i hate eclipse ? lol well ive been able to run a project from netbeans so i suppose what i have to do is try eclipse side.

Comment: If you hate Eclipse and you've successfully run a project from netbeans then by all means stick with netbeans! If you're familiar with the netbeans way of doing things then why change? For me its all about the speed of getting stuff done and your familiarity with netbeans might speed things up anyway! :)

Comment: Erm.. i just tried Eclipse and so far the plugin is pretty impressive on the eclipse base. AFter trying both i would suggest to new poeple to use eclipse rather than NetBEANS. You guys can alway use netbeans but you will have to figure out most of the xml configs stuff. Furthermore, the plugin include a powerful layout editor which can make your life way easier for multiple platforms compatibility with your app such android 2.2, 2.3 and 3.0.

Answer (score 9):

I develop almost everything in NetBeans.  However, for Android application development, Eclipse is the better IDE to use, as it simplifies a lot of simple tasks.

I prefer NetBeans generally, but Eclipse is way more tailored to Android development than NetBeans at the moment.

You will be more productive :

Answer (score -1):

Android offers an Eclipse Plugin per their web site.  Check out this link on the Android site:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html. For the beginning programmer new to Android the tight integration will allow ramp up to speed faster. One of the most highly regarded reference works by Reto Meier "Professional Android 4 Application Development" recommends Eclipse with the ADT Plug-in and makes no mention of Netbeans.

The ADT Plugin includes an Android Project Wizard, Virtual Device Manager and Emulator and especially the layout and resource editors for XML. Therefore you get the tightest integration to make it easiest for a programmer to ramp up quickly and begin to develop Android applications.

Android recommends Eclipse and the plugin, as do respected developers like Reto Meier over Netbeans.  (Despite the fact that a plugin does exist for Netbeans as helpfully provided below.)

My recommendation if you are new to Android development, use the Eclipse with ADT Plug-in. If you are a Netbeans veteran, stick with that.

Comment: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/19545/nbandroid is the NetBeans plugin for Android development.